# Disabling Datacenter Network Access to Cosmos DB Using Powershell / Azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb, firewall, azure-cli

I went through the documentation to find a way to disable the option **"Accept connections from within public Azure datacenters"** on the **"Firewall and Virtual networks"** settings page using Powershell, or Azure CLI, but I couldn't find any. Was anyone able to do that?

[image: Firewall and virtual networks settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this option of "Accept connections from within public Azure datacenters" is checked, an entry with value `0.0.0.0` is made into the allowed `IP Rannges`. This `0.0.0.0` IP address basically tells Cosmos DB to accept connections from public Azure datacenters. To block this access, you would simply need to remove `0.0.0.0` ip address from `ipRangeFilter`.

To get the properties, you will use [`az cosmos show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cosmosdb-show)

```
az cosmos show --name <cosmosdb-account-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name>`
```

To update the ip range, you will use [`az cosmos update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cosmosdb-update)

```
az cosmosdb update  --name <cosmosdb-account-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --ip-range-filter "104.42.195.92,40.76.54.131,52.176.6.30,52.169.50.45,52.187.184.26"
```

The above command will block access to the cosmos db from public Azure data centers but allow access from Azure Portal.

Equivalent commands in Azure PowerShell are [`Get-AzCosmosDBAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/get-azcosmosdbaccount?view=azps-4.2.0) and [`Update-AzCosmosDBAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/update-azcosmosdbaccount?view=azps-4.2.0).

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-firewall.